# I want to implement a simple pathfinding algorithm (A star) on RVIZ

Tags: ros, rviz, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to create an environment in RVIZ incorporating some form of pathfinding (such as A star).

Currently I just have an interactive marker moving around in the environment freely.  I want to have it follow some sort of waypoint through some sort of path planning.

I would also like to hopefully implement obstacles between point A and point B to test this path planning.

Can someone help suggest how I would approach this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164941/i-want-to-implement-a-simple-pathfinding-algorithm-(a-star)-on-rviz/) by [brandonlee503](https://answers.ros.org/users/18001/brandonlee503/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RVIZ isn't a simulator; it's a visualizer and, in the case of interactive markers, it can be used as an user interface, but it's primarily designed to display data from other sources.

If you're interested in path planning, you should write a node or a set of nodes which contain a map representation, do some planning on that map, and publish the things that you would like to visualize as ROS topics.

A few of the message types that RVIZ can visualize natively are occupancy grids (nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid), paths (nav_msgs/Path), poses (geometry_msgs/Pose), and interactive markers.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2